# The Actual Different: Spring boot @ComponentScan vs @Import when involving ConditionalOnClass

Tags: spring, spring-boot, objectmapper, component-scan, spring-autoconfiguration

### Context

I know there are a lot of posts regarding the comparison between these two. All of them just focus on `@Import` works on single Config file while `@ComponenentScan` will scan all config, bean, service files.

**I find something new, hope someone can give me a good explanation behind this:**

Prerequisite Artifact:

- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure
- org.springframework.boot.test

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = test1char.class)
@ComponentScan("org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson")
//@SpringBootTest(classes = test1char.class)
//@Import(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ObjectMapperTest {

    //cannot autowired: no such bean when using ComponenentScan
    // Can autowired when either using @Import 
    // or @SpringBootTest(classes = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.class)

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    void main() {
        var date = LocalDateTime.now();//LocalDateTime
        String s;
        try {
            s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(date);
            System.out.println(s);
        }catch (JsonProcessingException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

       
    }
}
```

ObjectMapper bean producer class:
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class for reference

```
@AutoConfiguration
@ConditionalOnClass({ObjectMapper.class})
public class JacksonAutoConfiguration {

    .... omit
    @Configuration(
        proxyBeanMethods = false
    )
    @ConditionalOnClass({Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.class})
    static class JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration {
        JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration() {
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean
        ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            return builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
        }
    }
```

### Issue

**Basically the ObjectMapper cannot autowired: no such bean when using ComponenentScan. But it can be autowired when either using @Import or @SpringBootTest(classes = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.class)**

**Note: test1char.class is just a dummy class so that it has a context while not using the default SpringBootApplication which has everything in class path**

I know it must have something to do with **ConditionalOnClass** which requires some class in jar org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson to be in classpath. So I boldly guess only @Import and @SprngBoot and @SpringBootTest can load class or package to be in classpath?
**That's why quite often ObjectMapper cannot be autoconfigured in @SpringBootTest annotated integration test as we often forgot to add the jar to it.**

#### Update

Hate to say with @EnableAutoConfiguration it works all good like below:
@ComponentScan("org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson")
@EnableAutoConfiguration

#### Update

Actually @EnableAutoConfiguration alone also works without @ComponentScan.

-- One who is always confused by SpringBoot config xD

#### Attachment: Condition Report output in Intellij when using @ComponenetScan

## ============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT

### Positive matches:

```
None
```

### Negative matches:

```
None
```

### Exclusions:

```
None
```

### Unconditional classes:

```
None
```

Comment: Update title as well so please don't do the quick judge

Comment: autoconfigurations aren't detected by an componentscan because they aren't components.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry can you give a bit more context? which issue are you trying to comment on?

Comment: Your question why they aren't detected by componentscan.

Comment: @M.Deinum  the job of `@ComponentScan` is to scan given packages and register beans annotated with Stereotype annotations (`@Component`, `@Configuration`, `@Service`, `@Repository`)

Comment: Trust me I know what the job of `@ComponentScan` is as well as `@Import`. You shouldn't use those on tests they work by accident not by design. It is an auto configuration whcih will work when that is enabled if not it won't work.

Comment: Ok I got what you mean JacksonAutoConfiguration is not Bean annotated. It is annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. Then I don't see any reason why `@Import` works @M.Deinum

Comment: @M.Deinum And isn't it also meaning that `I@mport` can `@EnableAutoConfiguration`